# How can I specify a different disk to be root in grub.cfg when running grub-mkconfig (from script/noninteractively)?

Tags: linux, grub

I am setting up an automated installer-system to install customized Ubuntu 12 and other operating systems onto disks, which will be removed and then permanently installed into new computers.

The problem is generating grub configuration -- if I run `grub-mkconfig` on the installer system, then it will put the UUID of the installer system's disk in rather than the target disk.  Is there a way to tell grub-mkconfig which disk I want to use as root?  If I chroot to the new system will it use whatever UUID that filesystem seems to be on?  Or do I have to resort to `sed` to replace the `search` commands in grub.cfg?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `chroot` will be fine, **however**, be sure that the system you `chroot` from fit to the system that you `chroot` into.

The `chroot` is used to move an operating system to a new disk without rebooting, installing an operating system, and other tasks that require installation of a new file system.

How to `chroot` with the correct mounts, correspond to the present system (Kernel) to a new file system. Install and setup GRUB 2 and possibly doing more tasks.

1) Mount your normal system partition. X is the drive letter. Y is the partition number:
`sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`

2) If you are using a separate boot disk or partition, it must be mounted (where sdXY is the /boot partition designation):
`sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot`

3) Mount the critical virtual filesystems (Kernel):
`for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done`

4) Chroot into the new file system: 
`sudo chroot /mnt`

5) Install GRUB 2 on the drive that the BIOS is set up to boot. If the drive is part of a RAID setup, repeat the command with all drive letters used in the array.
(Only specify a drive letter because the master boot record is installed in a very specific way):
`grub-install /dev/sdX`

6) Generate the GRUB 2 menu file (grub.cfg):
`update-grub`

7) Perform other tasks such as updates, install applications, configure, etc:
`...`

8) Exit chroot:
`CTRL-D` on the keyboard

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using chroot to do this, but first I manually changed the UUID of my target disk in grub.cfg on the target disk.  I used the `blkdev` command to find out the UUID of the target disk partition.  It looks something like this ($targetdir is the target filesyste mmounted, $diskdev is the disk device as seen from the host system, e.g. /dev/sdb, and $partitiondev is the disk partition, e.g. /dev/sdb1).  At this point I've already partitioned the disk, done mkfs, mounted it, then copied the desired contents of the new filesystem to the disk.

```
targetuuid=`blkid -s UUID -o value $partitiondev`
test -n "$targetuuid" || error "Could not determine UUID for $partitiondev"
sed --in-place=orig 's/search .*/search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root $targetuuid/' $targetdir/boot/grub/gub.cfg || error "Error setting correct UUID in $targetdir/boot/grub/grub.cfg"
mount -o bind /dev $targetdir/dev 
# could also bind other pseudo-filesystems like /proc as in Diblo Dk's answer.
chroot $targetdir grub-install --no-floppy --recheck $diskdev
umount $targetdir/dev # don't forget to unmount this first otherwise you can't unmount $targetdir later
```

[By the way, in case anyone else encounters a few tangential problems I had in doing this -- I used the "buildroot" tool to make a minimal Linux system in an initramfs to load from a network boot (pxe).  If you enable util-linux *and* select mount/umount under "install utilities", then a slightly broken version of mount is installed (replacing the built-in mount command in busybox), which seems to crash all the time.  Also, I had to enable use of devtmpfs in kernel config, and select devtmpfs in buildroot, so that rebinding the /dev filesystem would work -- I guess in the version of busybox I have the bind option to mount only seems to work if you are rebinding a filesystem not a directory within a filesystem.
This is all with buildroot version 2013.05, which uses busybox version 1.21.1, util-linux 2.22.2. Maybe these have been fixed since.]